# How to automate Outlook using Token authorization using Selenium Java? Since using SMTP Port its not working due to Changes made by Micro soft Team

Tags: authentication, selenium-webdriver, outlook, token, smtp-auth

Due to authorization, i.e. 535 5.7.139 Authentication fails, SmtpClientAuthentication is deactivated for the Mailbox, SMTP authentication will not be used at this time in the Organisation, according to automated outlook using Selenium Java.

Please assist me with automating Outlook using another method.I.e., using Java and Selenium code coupled with Token authorization.

Comment: See [Enable or disable authenticated client SMTP submission (SMTP AUTH) in Exchange Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission)

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Since SMTP is blocked due to security issue Kindly let me know if any other solutions there to send a mail from Outlook via Tokenization using Java with Selenium .  Thanks